# Cronic Behavior of URL

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

When I am using URL `www.mywebsite.com/Inquiry.aspx` it is working very fine with the URL and the Page contains all `.css` and `.js` files, BUT when I am changing the URL to `www.mywebsite.com/Inquiry.aspx/`

It is giving me the whole page with bunch of errors with `.css` file and `.js`

What I need to do in this case?

How can I open the same page without any error of `.css` and `.js`?

Comment: Use absolute url to your page (eg `/css/rules.css`) and not relative like `../css/rules.css` because probably is pass the last slash for directory and fail to find the correct directory.

Comment: @Aristos is more than likely spot on here. Also, what's a `.jquery`??

Comment: @Aristos but my pages is situated in different folders so the reference of .css is not able to find that folders using (eg /css/rules.css).

Comment: @James .js file references

Comment: @James Probably have mix the javascript with the jquery library....

Comment: @cracker Test first what I am propose you, and then we talk again :)

Comment: @Aristos i have tried using /css/.css but it's not able to take reference inside the folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolve using

```
<link runat="server" href="<%= ResolveURL("~/css/main.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: +1 this is what I was getting at (although I said `Url.Content` - had my MVC hat on :-D). These methods automatically resolve the page for you and work with nested resources etc.

Answer (score 1):

**After some tests I found that** if you place relative urls on your links, and the links **are not inside the header**, and add the last slash on the url, then its consider as directory and fail to find and load.

So this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

can be written with absolute url as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

and not be affected from the directory that you are now.

Please note that this can be an issue only under certain circumstance, like the slash on the end of the file, and not place it on the header, or in general not automatic correct the url with code.

Comment: Given it's ASP.NET the OP should really use `@Url.Content("~/css/style.css")`

Comment: @James yes of course it can be use that too. I usually avoid that because its add one more search and replace on the page, that I know for sure where I can find my resource, but yes, if the dir is change you can use it.

Comment: it's not just that you can do it, it's more reliable because it would handle Virtual Directories which your proposed solution wouldn't.

Comment: @James If you like you can edit the answer and add it, or add a new answer with it, (and I vote it with pleasure).

Comment: @James i think you have suggested this for the mvc in which i can use the @Url.Content("~/css/style.css") isn't it?

Comment: @cracker `Url.Content` works in ASP.NET aswell, however, I just realised I used MVC syntax (d'oh). It would be `<%= Url.Content("~/css/style.css") %>`

Comment: @James i think it's ResolveUrl instead of Url.Content

Comment: @cracker ah, maybe I got myself confuddled... I thought you could use `Url.Content` ASP.NET (yeah, ResolveUrl would be the equivalent then).

Comment: i have used that and it's workingand i have also posted new answer for this. Many thanks @james and Aristos :) :)